# AngularJs ui-route "could not resolve state" error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im new to AngularJs and I'm trying to get this ui-route working but no luck. This is a snippet of my .js file containing the route configure.

```
//object for routing
var route = angular.module('route', ["ui.router"])

// configure the routing        
route.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // send to profile page
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/personal_info");

    $stateProvider        // route for personal info
    .state('personal_info', {
            url: "/personal_info",
            templateUrl : 'personal_info.html' ,
            controller : 'persController'
    })
});
```

And this is my html file where I try to inject the ui-veiw and implement the nav bar with the routing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='app'>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="client_UI.js"></script>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mycss.css">  </head>
 <body>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script><!-- navigation bar -->

    <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="brand" ui-sref="#">Home</a>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li><a class="active" ui-sref="personal_info">Personal Info</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="cog_health">Cognitive Health</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="gen_health">General Health</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

<div class="container">
<div ui-view></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting this error that says "Error: Could not resolve 'peronal_info' from state ''
transitionTo@http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:1971 ...". Can someone please give me a hint on how to fix this problem?

Thanks

UPDATE: I've fixed a syntax problem and now I'm getting an error that looks like this ,

```
"GET http://localhost:3000/personal_info.html [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 1ms]"
```

Comment: Shouldn't the angular-ui-router.js be loaded before the app.js (angular.js or client_ui.js)?

Comment: I modified my code and loaded the angular-ui-router.js before angular.js and client_ui.js but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: If personal_info is your only state, have you tried changing it to index? Not entirely sure, but ui-router may need an index state by default. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: What do you mean by index state? Is it something like ...  "<a class="brand" ui-sref="#">Home</a>"? And I'm only showing one state in the code. I have others but I need to make this work before I head to the others. Thanks for the help, much appreciated

Comment: Since it is an 401 it led me to look for an incorrectly defined base tag, but there was none.

But what url do you use to get your "index.html" (or what you have called it)... since your not in html5 mode, there may be some residual issues when your working in virtual directories...

Comment: Posted an example and potential edit.

Comment: Ohh, and btw its access to your template(Url) that is the problem, the router has identifies your state just fine. Try using "template: 'Hello world'" instead to verify your state config

Comment: Jens, you're correct. When I put in Hello World as a template, the html displays it fine so the problem is the templateUrl. I tried adding in a locationProvider line to help with the html5Mode but it's making things worst.

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: An update for the same, i did all you have asked but the problem was persistent, so getting the hint that templateUrl is the problem, i have the templateUrl has 'jobDetail', and when i changed it to 'jobdetail' it started working !! Rather Strange, can anyone explain what is the reason behind the templateUrl ? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of my app.js with ui-router.

```
'use strict';


  angular.module('srcApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ui.router'
])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('lang', {
        url: '/:lang',
        templateUrl: '../views/interface.html',
        controller:'MainCtrl'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/en');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/en');
  });
```

I'd suggest trying something with yours like:

```
//object for routing
var app = angular.module('app', ["ui.router"]);

// configure the routing        
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider        // route for personal info
    .state('index', {
            url: "/personal_info",
            templateUrl : 'personal_info.html' ,
            controller : 'persController'
    });

    // send to profile page
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/personal_info");
});
```

Comment: You're a life saver! Thanks a lot. Can you please explain why we're using 'index' as the state and not personal_info?

Comment: I'm just not sure (hence laziness on this holiday) if ui-router requires an index state or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But I resolve mine by using the latest release of angular-ui-router.js from unpkg.com. I use version 3.2.